# How to count how many particles are in each meter?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having a hard time getting a counter to work!

I have an array of distances (in meters):

```
d= [250.4, 250.6, 250.7, 250.7, 251.6, 251.7, 252.2, 253.5]
```

Each distance corresponds to a particle. I would like to count how many particles are in each meter.

So for example, there are 4 particles between 250-251m, 2 particles between 251 to 252m, 1 particle between 252-253m, etc.

I know I need a `for` loop and I'm assuming a counter.

Comment: Post the code you wrote and explain specifically what error you are getting or what the output looks like and why it is not 100% correct.

Comment: going to need a counter for each interval you're counting and use the floor function to check. like i=250.2- floor(i) == 250 counter+=1

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a dictionary with integer keys:

```
counts = {}
data = [250.4, 250.6, 250.7, 250.7, 251.6, 251.7, 252.2, 253.5]

for datum in data:
    meter = int(datum)
    counts.setdefault(meter, 0)
    counts[meter] += 1

assert counts == {250: 4, 251: 2, 252: 1, 253: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (hardcoded):

```
d= [250.4, 250.6, 250.7, 250.7, 251.6, 251.7, 252.2, 253.5]
newlist=[]
for elem in d:
   if 250<elem<251:
      newlist.append(4)
   elif 251<elem<252:
      newlist.append(2)
   elif 252<elem<253:
      newlist.append(1)
   #etc
print(newlist)
```

Or this (not as hardcoded):

```
d= [250.4, 250.6, 250.7, 250.7, 251.6, 251.7, 252.2, 253.5]
listy=[[250,4],[251,2],[252,1]]
newlist=[]
for ele in d:
   for elem in listy:
      if str(elem[0])==str(ele)[0:-2]:
         newlist.append(elem[1])
print(newlist)
```